# Grails: Use several closures inside another one

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, criteria

I am creating a criteria depending on several factors. Currently I'm using nested closures in the following way:

Utils.groovy

```
static def statusAndOrderCriteria = { x ->
    ...
    Utils.commonOrderCriteria.delegate = delegate
    Utils.commonOrderCriteria(x)
}

static def commonOrderCriteria = { x ->
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
Alert.createCriteria().list({
    Utils.statusAndOrderCriteria.delegate = delegate
    Utils.statusAndOrderCriteria(x)
})
```

I want to use several closures, such as:

```
Alert.createCriteria().list({
    Utils.firstCriteria(a)
    Utils.secondCriteria(b)
    Utils.statusAndOrderCriteria(x)
})
```

I don't know how to achieve that. I know that I can't be overwriting the delegate object several times on the same closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a GORM criteria query, the delegate of the closure is an instance of `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`. What you can do is modify your `Util` closures to accept this builder as a parameter. Then, delegate the method calls to the builder. Here's an example:

```
class Utils {
    static def statusAndOrderCriteria = { criteriaBuilder, x ->
        criteriaBuilder.eq('foo', x)
        Utils.commonOrderCriteria(criteriaBuilder, x)
    }

    static def commonOrderCriteria = { criteriaBuilder, x ->
        criteriaBuilder.lt('bar', x)
    }
}
```

Then you can use the static closures in `Util` like this:

```
Alert.createCriteria().list({
    Utils.firstCriteria(delegate, a)
    Utils.secondCriteria(delegate, b)
    Utils.statusAndOrderCriteria(delegate, x)
})
```

*Hint: If the closures were not static properties you'd be able to avoid constantly having to pass the delegate*, like this:

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
class Utils {
    HibernateCriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder

    def statusAndOrderCriteria = { x ->
        criteriaBuilder.foo()
        Utils.commonOrderCriteria(x)
    }

    def commonOrderCriteria = { x ->
        criteriaBuilder.bar()
    }
}

Alert.createCriteria().list({
    def utils = new Utils(delegate)

    utils.firstCriteria(a)
    utils.secondCriteria(b)
    utils.statusAndOrderCriteria(x)
})
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I had to look up the `TupleConstructor` annotation - for anyone else, it provides the constructor that allows for 'new Utils(delegate').

Comment: Oh thank you. Have you seen the other Groovy built in ast's? The whole concept is just f*****g awesome!

Comment: I'm only familiar with the `@Builder` AST

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (the hint section). Thanks a lot! You are the Legolas of Groovy